# Sopaui git jenkins integration

Tags: java, shell, github, jenkins, soapui

Hi I am using below code in build step in jenkin

```
#!/bin/bash
pwd
cd ./eclipse-workspace/SoapUiTest
pwd
javac -classpath "lib/* -d ./bin ./src/defaultPackage/*.java" 
java -cp "bin;lib/* org.testng.TestNG testng.xml"
```

while running job i am getting below error

javac: no source files
Usage: javac  
use -help for a list of possible options
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
(to execute a class)
or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
(to execute a jar file)
where options include:
-d32      use a 32-bit data model if available
-d64      use a 64-bit data model if available
-server   to select the "server" VM
-zero     to select the "zero" VM
-dcevm    to select the "dcevm" VM
The default VM is server,
because you are running on a server-class machine.
-cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
-classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
A : separated list of directories, JAR archives,
and ZIP archives to search for class files.

Answer (score 1):

An obvious error is the mixure of flags in flag values in javac command:

```
#!/bin/bash
pwd
cd ./eclipse-workspace/SoapUiTest
pwd
javac -classpath "lib/*" -d "./bin" "./src/defaultPackage/*.java"  
java -cp "bin;lib/* org.testng.TestNG testng.xml"
```

`javac` command explanation: you specify where to find additional class binaries that the compilation depends on, where to output the compiled files and finally where to read the sources from.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response, could you please elaborate this lil more as i have specify the source "./eclipse-workspace/SoapUiTest", could you share any example like what should be the source in that case.

Comment: @DeveshJoshi I do not understand what exactly you mean in this comment